# Writing to .ini file - SimpleIni SetValue not doing anything, despite appearing to succeed

Tags: c++, windows, guid, ini

So I've been trying to read and write from my windows service's .ini file.  I am storing the ini file temporarily at 'C:\test\CppWindowsService.ini'.  The program reads the ini just fine, but **has trouble setting the value in the ini file.  It appears to update the value, but in reality does not do anything.**  I am using brofield's SimpleIni available at github, something I've seen numerous people online using for their ini parsing needs.  You can find it [here](https://github.com/brofield/simpleini).

Things I've tried/checked thus far:

- Security Settings:  the Administrators, Domain Admins, System and I all have read/write access.  This section of code is being ran as my Domain Admin.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance!

```
bool readini()
{
    // Load .ini file and retrieve ClientGuid **
    CSimpleIniA ini;
    ini.SetUnicode();
    ini.LoadFile("C:\\test\\CppWindowsService.ini");
    const char * pVal = ini.GetValue("GUID", "Clientguid", NULL);

    std::cout << "pVal:" << pVal << std::endl;
    std::string test(pVal);  // Had to convert pVal to string for unknow reason: 
    if (test == "noguid")    // const char * "noguid" != const char[7] "noguid" ???
    {                        // Aren't these the exact same thing?...  Compiler wasn't
        // generate guid **  // throwing the error, but the if statement wouldn't pass 
        GUID initguid;       // the condition until I did this.
        HRESULT hCreateGuid = CoCreateGuid(&initguid);

        // generate bstr from guid **
        wchar_t* bstrGuid;
        StringFromCLSID(initguid, &bstrGuid);
        std::wcout << bstrGuid << std::endl;

        // transform bstr to str **
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << bstrGuid;
        std::string guid = ss.str();

        // set .ini clientguid with generated guid **
        SI_Error rc = ini.SetValue("GUID", "Clientguid", guid.c_str());
        if (rc < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        printf("key: %s\n", rc == SI_INSERTED ?
            "inserted" : "updated");

        ::CoTaskMemFree(bstrGuid);
    }
}
```

The output from the three various cout/wcout/print statements:

```
pval: noguid
{D002CD3F-6434-47E9-8246-06884FDE1FEA}
key: updated
```

Ini format:

```
[GUID]
Clientguid = noguid
```

I've only included the SimpleIni.h file, as the others look like they aren't really useful for me.  This seems to be ok, and as far as I can tell, it isn't the issue... but please let me know if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the INI file using the command:

```
ini.SaveFile("C:\\test\\CppWindowsService.ini");
```